# Shell function in a file not running when invoked with ". file args..."

Tags: bash, function, shell, scripting

I am learning bash stuff, and I think I'm confused about functions.  When I write a function(?) to repeat a character a desired number of times like this:

```
_repeat()
{
    #@ USAGE: _repeate string number
    _REPEAT=$1
    while [ ${#_REPEAT} -lt $2 ]
    do
        _REPEAT=$_REPEAT$_REPEAT$_REPEAT
    done

    _REPEAT=${_REPEAT:0:$2} ## Trim to desired length

    printf "%s\n" "$_REPEAT"
}
```

and I call it on the command line with `. _repeat "hi" 5` nothing prints to the terminal.  If I take away the function name and brackets, and just have the code, and do `chmod +x /pathtofile/_repeat` and call `repeat "hi" 5` it does print to the command line.

I think I'm misunderstanding something about functions but I'm not sure what.

Comment: `. _repeat hi 5` is reading from a *file* named `_repeat`, with the arguments `hi` and `5` defined in `"$@"` while the file's contents are being executed. If you want to call a function that's already defined in your current shell, you just run `_repeat "hi" 5`, with no leading dot.

Comment: Why are you including the dot(`.`)? run it without it

Comment: Maybe you have that function definition *in a file*? Sourcing the file ("dotting it in") defines the function in your current shell, it *doesn't* run the function, unless you modify the file's contents to do so explicitly (f/e, adding a final line like `if (( $# )); then _repeat "$@"; fi`.

Comment: BTW, if you don't declare function-local variables `local` (or use `declare`, which serves as a synonym), then they leak into surrounding scope.

Comment: As another aside -- all-caps variable names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or system; see fourth paragraph of the relevant POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html. Names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I have a file written in a text editor.  So if I define the function in the terminal window itself, I don't have to 'dot it in'?  I'm curious then, how can I see which functions have been defined in the terminal, how can I change or remove them?

Comment: @A.Pizzle To see declared functions in bash: `typeset -f`. To see variables you can use: `( set -o posix ; set )`

Comment: Since accepting an answer is how a question is marked closed/resolved, it's important to actually *accept an answer*, as opposed to editing it into the question. When a question is answered in comments it's acceptable to add and accept your own answer (if the folks adding said comments aren't inclined to add a formal answer themselves), but it still should be added *as an answer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's Going On

When you run:

```
. _repeat hi 5
```

...that's running the contents from the file `_repeat` in your current shell, with `$1` being `hi` and `$2` being `5`.

**However, the contents given in the question merely *define a function*; they don't *invoke* that function, so the function body never takes effect.**

---

#### Modifying Your Script To Invoke The Function

Simply add the following line to the end:

```
if (( $# )); then _repeat "$@"; fi
```

This will invoke the function `_repeat` if the script is passed a nonzero argument list. (If passed no arguments, sourcing the script will merely define the function without executing it).

---

#### Invoking Your Function Without The Script

At any point after the function has been defined, you can execute it by just calling it as a command, without the dot:

```
_repeat hi 5
```